# How to auto arrange all sub views?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` at the top of a `UIView`, below many `UIControls` are there like buttons, table view... Possibilities are user can give multiple lines in `UITextView`, in that case I have to expand(increase height) for `UITextview` to show two lines, If `UITextview` height increase every other controls should go down accordingly, How to do it in iOS ? I heard android they are auto arranging easily, Is there any way to do like this in iOS?

Where should I concentrate? Any ideas will be helpful. Thanx.

Comment: you should use autolayout for it. It arrange your view according to given size and given constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use autolayout for achieving this.

[raywenderlich autolaout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

[developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html)

[Auto Layout video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lexSrQbHW6s)

[About Cocoa Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html)

This tutorial helps you to understand autolayout in a better way.

Comment: You are giving the green check to a Google search?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at auto layout, it's available from ios6 onwards. It will allow you to easily (some even non programmatically) specify constraints to be maintained while the view hierarchy is being displayed. For a good tutorial see [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).

If you are working on iOS5 or below I would recommend the following :
I am assuming that all your views are direct children of the textView, even if that isn't the case the grandchildren views (and further ancestors) will move automatically once their parent moves down.

```
for (UIView* view in yourTextView.subviews)
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,Y_DELTA_VALUE);
//Y_DELTA_VALUE is the amount you want to move the subviews down by, the 
//(amount of height the textView increases by)/2
```